# Should I expense my personal car accident?

Tags: professionalism, expenses, company-car

While specifically getting office supplies for my office I had 2 punctured tyres, had to tow the car and replace the tyres.

Since the trip was exclusively for work, should I ask for reimbursement from my company? Would any of you have a similar experience?

Comment: Have you been ordered to use your personal car for getting office supplies, or was it your idea to get some and your idea to use your personal car for this?

Comment: Getting those supplies is part of my duties and their was no alternative to get it than personal car or taxi.

Comment: I guess it depends a lot on **a)** was it clear and written down that you conduct business using your private car **b)** who needs to make sure that car is intact and working (for example who pays for fuel and regular repairs, what happens if you decide to sell it) **c)** Can you prove it was an accident instead of normal wear and does that make a difference in the light of what you found out about b). 
I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only you can find out.

Comment: Your profile indicates that you are in the USA. Is that correct? Adding a country tag to this question may be a good idea.

Comment: It's a clear case of expense practice generic enough to apply in many situations.

Comment: No. Accidents in your own car are your responsibility.

Comment: Kinda related - I hope you've mentioned to your insurance carrier that you occasionally use your car for business.  They might try to use that to deny a claim if you haven't...

Comment: If collecting office supplies using your vehicle are part of your normal and expected duties as your employment contract says, then you are already being reimbursed for the use of your car - you are being paid for your job.  If an accident occurred (did you drift into a kerb?) then claim on your insurance.  If you simply got two flat tyres due to debris on the road, thats not an accident, its just a bad day and usually insurance won't pay out because its classed as "wear and tear".  In either case, an employer almost certainly isn't obliged to pay for the damage.

Answer (score 4):

Blatantly no. The damage was caused by general wear and tear on your car - trying to charge the company for it is like saying "I need you to pay for my haircut because I decided my hair was too long while I was at work".

Comment: I had the tyre changed recently. This was no wear and tear. This was an accident while conducting business with a personal vehicle.

Comment: @Ghaag if it was an accident then claim on your insurance.  If it was simply two flat tyres then it wasn't an accident, it was normal wear and tear (yes, unexpected flat tyres are wear and tear, stuff happens).

Comment: I would say the chances of any company paying for the tires/towing would approach 0.